# Why can't I perform an inplace swap on a Python array?

Tags: python, arrays, sorting

I was trying to implement cyclic sort, but ran into an infinite loop when I tested my function on [0, 2, 1, 3]. Here is my code:

```
def sort(row):
    for i in range(len(row)):
        if row[i] != i: #should be while instead of if, but would loop if used while
            row[i], row[row[i]] = row[row[i]], row[i]
            print(row)
    return row

sort([0, 2, 1, 3]) #returns [0, 2, 1, 3]
```

What is going on here?

Comment: FTR: by contrast, something like `row[0], row[1] = row[1], row[0]` does seem to work.

Comment: @KellyBundy I really didn't expect there to be a duplicate for this. Is this a common algorithm that people try to implement?

Comment: I am not sure I follow your logic - what is `row[i] != i` for? You are comparing a value with an index, why?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel I've seen it asked quite a few times. (Well, not necessarily this *algorithm*, but the issue this is about).